Once Upon a Time-Fanfiction Title Our Own Kind of Family
I am looking for a Once Upon a Time fanfiction by  Findingtallahasee. The title is Our Own Kind of Family. I believe it was posted on Fanfiction.net. Snow escapes the curse with Emma. She finds that August escaped the curse as well. She raises Emma and August.

Does the current answer work for you? If so, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Ditto with the answers to some of your other questions.

Our Own Kind of Family
by JustanOutlaw

Snow's still pregnant when the curse is set, leading to her becoming August's mother. She raises both he and Emma for nearly a decade until they get a clue that could lead them home.

There's a link on the right-side of that page to see Chapter 2. It appears there are only two chapters.

Note that your search was likely clouded by using the wrong author. Finding Tallahassee is another FanFic for Once Upon a Time written by Brinley Emerson.
